# is there "phpmyadmin" for oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

I mean a php online script that connects to Oracle?  Or should I use navicat?  Is navicat that good?  Any other alternative?  I secretly hope that I will not be forced to use command line interface for a product that costs $40k (Well I am using the Express Edition. But anyway).

Comment: Wait a second... What's wrong with enterprise manager?

Answer (score 4):

Check out Oracle SQL Developer.  It's free, and it is a fully featured IDE.  [Find out more.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Comment: For the benefit of others: this solution is platform independent as it is implemented in Java. There are packages available for Linux and Mac OS X in addition to Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I use [PLSQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html). It's not online, but it beats command line interfaces. :)

Comment: interesting, i will have a look.

Comment: For the benefit of others: this solution is only available for Microsoft Windows platforms.

Answer (score 1):

As others have posted, I use SQL Developer for my IDE. However, if you are looking for a fully functional web interface like PHPMyAdmin, check out Oracle's [Application Express (Apex)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/index.html).

It's free, and although it's meant as a rapid web development tool, it has great tools to manage your schema, tables, and other objects.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer, you could use TOAD (Tool for Oracle Application Developers). It has both a paid for version and a free version.

In my experience the free version is easy to use and powerful enough for most users.

http://www.quest.com/toad/

Comment: For the benefit of others: this solution is only available for Microsoft Windows platforms.